# If else in sort JCL

Tags: sorting, if-statement, cobol, mainframe, jcl

I have a two requirements:

1. I must concatenate some fields from a file in a Cobol program. The way i must concatenate is based on one of the aforementioned field. The concatenated fields must be outputted in a new file.
2. I must then sort this new file with a sort utility invoked by JCL.

**The Issue**
I need to sort same file for 2 conditions. I have tried with ifthen outrec build. How can I sort it in one pass?

Here is a source-code example :

```
ID DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. FOO.    
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
FILE-CONTROL.
   Select Infil assign to inp001.
   Select Outfil assign to out001.
DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.
FD Infil.
01 Main.
     03 A.    
      05 ws-Pc.  Pic x(1).
      05 filler  Pic x(5).
     03 B.  Pic x(4).
     03 C.  Pic x(4).
     03 D.  Pic 9(13)V99.
     03 E.  Pic  x(13).

FD Outfil.
01 Temp Pic x(42).

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 file-flag Pic x(01).
  88 file-end value 'Y'.
  88 not-file-end value 'N'.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
 Open input Infil
 Open output Outfil
 read Infil
   at end
     set file-end to true
   not at end
     set not-file-end to true
 end-read

 Perform until file-end
     If  ws-Pc = 3
       String A B C Delimited by size
              into Temp
       End-String
     Else
        String A B C E Delimited by size
              into Temp
       End-String       
     End-if 

     Write Temp
     read Infil
       at end 
        Set file-end to true
     end-read
 end-Perform.
end program foo.
```

Here is the logic I need for the sort utility :

```
  If ws-Pc=3
    Sort(fieldA,fieldB)
  Else
    Sort(fieldA,fieldB,fieldE)
  End-if.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: SORT is *not* `JCL`. You write some `JCL` to run the SORT program. Your COBOL program could end with different return codes to indicate which sort you need. Then in the `JCL`you can create a step for each case and use `JCL IF` to select which step to run based on the return code of the COBOL program.

Comment: Sort fields =(1,6,ch,a,7,4,ch,a).   I have tried this for first condition it works fine..like this I need to sort same dataset for else condition.

Comment: How about using a COBOL `SORT`-statement with an `INPUT PROCEDURE` and/or `OUTPUT PROCEDURE` to concatenate the fields?

Comment: @user13766556
In the Sort Condition you type that you want to sort based on field D. However Field D does not exist in your result file. Is that normal ?

Comment: It's mistake..It is A,B,C,E only in else part

Answer (score 1):

I can propose you three variations :

1. If you are sure that your last 13 characters are the same (spaces for instance) in the case without a field E (ws-pc equal to three) you can just have this sysin:

```
SORT FIELDS=(1,6,CH,A,7,4,CH,A),EQUALS
```

Indeed, thanks to the equals all your inputs will keep their relative order once sorted. For the case ws-pc=3 it will be sorted according to field A and B. Field E plays no importance because it is the same for all.

2. If you are not sure that the last 13 characters are the same you can do it yourself:

```
INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=(1,1,CH,EQ,C'3'),BUILD=(1,14,13X)) 
SORT FIELDS=(1,6,CH,A,7,4,CH,A),EQUALS
```

This will force your last characters to be spaces.

3. If you don't want to use the "EQUALS" you can create your own ordering by appending a line number in the field E when it is unused. You then have to remove it.

```
INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=(1,1,CH,EQ,C'3'),BUILD=(1,14,SEQNUM,13,ZD)) 
SORT FIELDS=(1,6,CH,A,7,4,CH,A)
OUTREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=(1,1,CH,EQ,C'3'),BUILD=(1,14,13X))
```